# How to get ‘services for Unix administration’ and ‘telnet client’ under SUA

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, sua

I am not sure this is the right place to ask this question. I had a Windows Services for Unix(SFU) installed in XP system , so that contains C shell, korn shell, services for Unix administration and telnet client.
When I was installing same software on windows 2008 system I realized Windows Services for Unix (SFU) is changed to Subsystem for Unix based application(SUA) and is embedded with operating system. So I enabled it from windows features and again installed uitilities and SDK from the link which they provided. But now I am missing ‘services for Unix administration’ and ‘telnet client’ under ‘Subsystem for Unix based applications’ in all programs. Can any body guide me how to get ‘services for Unix administration’ and ‘telnet client’ under Subsystem for Unix based applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFU is legacy part which is replaced by SUA in later operating systems.Most of the features are embdded with SUA which is part of operating system now